# My domain.fr is web responsive but NOT the redirected domain.net on OVH. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, responsive-design, ovh

I've my landing page at [bubbleio.fr](http://www.bubbleio.fr) hosted by OVH in France. I've also have the [bubbleio.net](http://www.bubbleio.net) redirected to my .fr domain with OVH redirection settings.

The .fr domain page is web responsive and follow my mobile *vertical* screen size but not the .net domain page. The server/code is the same!!! I don't understand. If you have some clues ?

Answer (score 1):

just add this to the `<head>` of bubbleio.net 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: OK but bubbleio.net doesn't exist by itself, it is only a redirection to .fr !! I had a look to the html of .net... OVH doesn't use the original .fr and responsive `<meta name="viewport"'...` deseapear. I'll ask OVH support and give feed back later to this issue

Comment: I've changed redirection from invisible to visible .net is replace by .fr but doesn't matter really

Comment: After deeper search, OVH use iframe for "invisible" redirection but iframe doesn't support responsive meta like viewport...

Comment: i read there doc https://docs.ovh.com/ma/fr/domains/mutualise_guide_redirection_dun_nom_de_domaine/#redirection-invisible
i don't find any solution for your problem. The best solution is to do visible redirection 301